Converting UDF from postgres to snowflake
I’m currently trying to migrate some functions from postgres to Snowflake and having some trouble, I’m hoping someone can give some advice.
Within postgres I currently have a conversion function that basically does some simple checks and then does a lookup on a large conversions table, this works extremely well. I am unfortunately having a ton of trouble with adapting this to snowflake.
I have tried directly re-creating the function as follows
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conv_curr(
    _from_curr STRING,
    _to_curr STRING,
    _tstamp TIMESTAMP_TZ,
    _amount NUMERIC DEFAULT -1
)
RETURNS NUMERIC
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    CASE
        WHEN _from_curr = _to_curr THEN 1
        -- fiat conversions
        WHEN _from_curr = 'CAD' AND _to_curr = 'USD' THEN
            1 / (
                SELECT price 
                FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
                WHERE 
                    base = 'USD'
                    AND quote = 'CAD'
                    AND tstamp < _tstamp
                ORDER BY tstamp DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ) 
        WHEN _from_curr = 'USD' AND _to_curr = 'CAD' THEN
            (
                SELECT price 
                FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
                WHERE 
                    base = 'USD'
                    AND quote = 'CAD'
                    AND tstamp < _tstamp
                ORDER BY tstamp DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
        -- from fiat to crypto
        WHEN _from_curr = 'CAD' OR _from_curr = 'USD' THEN
            (
                SELECT price
                FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
                WHERE
                    base = _to_curr
                    AND quote = _from_curr
                    AND tstamp < _tstamp
                ORDER BY tstamp DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )

        -- crypto to fiat
        WHEN _to_curr = 'CAD' OR _to_curr = 'USD' THEN
            (
                SELECT price
                FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
                WHERE
                    base = _from_curr
                    AND quote = _to_curr
                    AND tstamp < _tstamp
                ORDER BY tstamp DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )

        -- crypto to crypto
        ELSE
        (
            SELECT price
            FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
            WHERE
                base = _from_curr
                AND quote = 'CAD'
                AND tstamp < _tstamp
            ORDER BY tstamp DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) / (
            SELECT price
            FROM CURRENCY_LOOKUP
            WHERE
                base = _to_curr
                AND quote = 'CAD'
                AND tstamp < _tstamp
            ORDER BY tstamp DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) 
    END * CASE WHEN _amount = -1 THEN 1 ELSE _amount END
$$

but get the error of “Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated” due to it being “unfolded” into a correlated subquery I believe.
I also tried with a UDTF but ran into the same issue.
I would really like to be able to contain this logic in a single sort of function for maintainability, if anyone has ideas it would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: the query above does run on its own but as soon as I try use it in a query e.g.
WITH
vals AS (
    SELECT 
        uuid,
        created,
        base,
        quote,
        base_amount,
        quote_amount
    FROM TRANSACTIONS
    ORDER BY created DESC
    LIMIT 10
)

SELECT 
    *,
    CONV_CURR(base, 'CAD', created, base_amount) AS value
FROM vals V
;

it gives the error, I have also tried converting this to a table function but same issue

Try using CTE in your function, rather than sub-queries in your select.

The postgresql function is think row based. where-as the snowflake model is table vs table. If your timestamps are per wildly different then "prebuild a table (or CTE) of lastest per day" might require an ASOF-JOIN https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/asof-join  But your best performance would come from knowning the time limits of the outter table, thus be able to filter the currency table, and also use equi joins to get exact matches for each tranaction
